# ffmpeg - How to filter video when record Window Application in the same time

Tags: filter, merge, ffmpeg, record

I have a problem when record Window Application and filter (overlay, audio mixing...) with others filter video.

This code work perfectly :

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -draw_mouse 0 -i title="Main" -vf crop=850:480:156:100 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -y ok.mp4   (With Main is my Application)
```

But this code bellow doesn't:

```
ffmpeg  -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -y -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -draw_mouse 0 -i title="Main" -vf crop=850:480:156:100 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -stream_loop 999 -i "filter/filter.mp4" -filter_complex "[2:v]scale=385:216, setdar=dar=16/9[v1]; [2:v]scale=385:216, setdar=dar=16/9[v2]; [v1][v2]blend=shortest=1:all_opacity=1[v3]; movie=filter/nds_bg.mp4:loop=999,setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB), scale=640:360[v4] ;[v4][v3]overlay=shortest=1:x=20:y=130;[2:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,asetrate=8.5/10*44100,atempo=10/8.5,lowpass=f=2500,highpass=f=400,volume
=3,bass=g=-30,equalizer=f=10.5:width_type=o:width=1:g=-30, equalizer=f=31.5:width_type=o:width=1:g=-
30,equalizer=f=63:width_type=o:width=1:g=-10, equalizer=f=125:width_type=o:width=1:g=-20,equalizer=f=250:width_type=o:width=1:g=-1.5,equalizer=f=500:width_type=o:width=1:g=-20,equalizer=f=1000:width_type=o:width=1:g=-20,equalizer=f=8000:width_type=o:width=3:g=1,equalizer=f=16000:width_type=o:width=3:g=1" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 26 -g 30 -b:30 
800k -shortest -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -preset:v ultrafast -ar 44100 -f flv -bufsize 3000k -s 640x360 out.mp4
```

I think this code need to output to video first

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -y -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -draw_mouse 0 -i title="Main" -vf crop=850:480:156:100 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline
```

Please show me how to merge these code or any solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do you wish to filter the main input? The filtergraph activity doesn't interact currently with the main input at all. Also see some puzzling filter actions specified.

Comment: #Gyan : Thank you so much. I want to create the first command is main input, and concat them into the second command. I mean is Record the window application (include audio and video) and overlay it on a background. Sorry for my bad English.